# How to split string by character with exceptions (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, split

I want to process a CSV file.
But there are certain problems with processing it:

I need to split the lines every ;
Normally i'd use the .split method btu in this case there are exceptions:

A line can have empty "cells" so it could look like `x;y;z;;a;;;b`
I still need to get the empty ones in the array.
For example

```
array[0] = "x";
array[1] = "y";
array[2] = "z";
array[3] = "";
```

and so on.
Another exception is:
There is one cell that contains html code (which has ";" in it).
So the string shouldn't get split if the ; is between "".
Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing data of this form is a common problem, and has been solved by CSV parsers. You could use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html) and change the delimiter to `;` instead of the default `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using api [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Here is the small example of doing same,

```
public class OpenCSVExample {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CSVReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        //Get the CSVReader instance with specifying the delimiter to be used
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("SampleCSVFile.csv"),';');
        String [] nextLine;
        //Read one line at a time
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
        {
            for(String token : nextLine)
            {
                //Print all tokens
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Above example is taken from this reference [ParseCSVFiles](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/parse-csv-files-in-java/), check it out for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with reg exp.

```
public void regExpSeparateWithSemicolon() {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String[] result = null;
    String testString = null;
    String regularExpression = "(?!=\",\");";
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(
                new File("/home/domain/immo/Documents/SampleCsv.csv"));//Path to csv file
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            //String testString = "x;y;z;;a;\";\";b";
            testString = scanner.next();
            testString = testString.replaceAll("\";\"","\",\"");                                
            result = testString.split(regularExpression);
            for(int index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                System.out.println("result["+counter+++"] = "+
                        result[index].replace(",", ";"));
            }                   
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured :"+fnf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured :"+e);
    } finally {
        if(null != scanner) {
            scanner.close();    
        }               
    }
}
```

SampleCsv.csv

> x;y;z;;a;;;";";b
>
> 1;2;3;;4;;;";";5

---

O/P

---

```
result[0] = x
result[1] = y
result[2] = z
result[3] = 
result[4] = a
result[5] = 
result[6] = 
result[7] = ";"
result[8] = b
result[9] = 1
result[10] = 2
result[11] = 3
result[12] = 
result[13] = 4
result[14] = 
result[15] = 
result[16] = ";"
result[17] = 5
```

> I can't figure out how to make it work without the replaceAll.

I hope someone will find it.